# Why does my laptop shut down immediately after replacing the power connector?

Tags: power-supply, laptop-repair

I have an HP Compaq 610

Recently my laptop fell from my bed right on the power connector. I've changed the power connector with a new one. There is power to the laptop. But the now the laptop shuts down immediately after it is turned on. I can hear the CPU cooler spinning but after less than 5 seconds the laptop shuts down. What can be the issue? How can I fix it? What should I investigate? The service that fixed my power connector couldnt tell what could be the issue.

---

**More info:**

Мy laptop is not under warranty, so I took it to the best recommended service (not official, not shop repair). The needle in the power connector was broken, heavily pushed in laptop interior. They've opened the laptop and said that my DC-connector is broken. They've replaced it with new one. The point is that my laptop gets the power, and after some small amount of time (less than 5 seconds) it stops, i mean like looses the power. I've tried it with and without battery, its the same. It does not even come to boot screen, not even have powered up screen.

I'm using a 8.5 volts connector.

There is no battery light, my laptop is 3 years old. But there is light diode right above the connector. That light diode twinkles blue and then white right when the computer power collapses.

Generally, it powers up again right after each turn off, but there are cases when I had to push the power button twice.

Comment: **Welcome to Super User!** *Caution*: Never use a laptop on your bed! It will collect a lot of dust and will overheat your CPU and GPU in no time. Make sure you at least put a flat solid thing underneath it if you do want to do it. Something like an Atlas should do the job... :)

Comment: When the power adaptor is plugged in, does the battery charge light come on?

Comment: There is no battery light, my laptop is 3 years old :). But there is light diode right above the connector. That light diode twinkles blue and then white right when the computer power collapses.

Comment: I think the problem with a non official repair service is that they don't know the exact schematics and can troubleshoot towards the actual problem. They might as well done something wrong when soldering your laptop by the looks of it, something might be getting too much power which causes a safety shutdown...

Comment: Does that safety shutdown works on hardware level if i may say?

Comment: @NikolaMKD: Dunno how exactly it would work, might as well be your power supply that stops providing when the laptop uses too much. But surely some safety is in place to prevent your laptop from catching damage, if they did something wrong. *But we can't tell, it might have been the laptop drop...*

Comment: What could be causing this on-off problem from the drop? I mean, what could suffered and now prevents the system to power up? The service, tried to investigate, it took them about a week, but they did not managed to find what is causing the on-off problem.

Comment: Does BIOS battery could suffered too?

Comment: Does it ever last more than 5 seconds, and, can you turn it on straight away after it has turned off?

Comment: No, it can last less but no more than 4-5. Sometimes I can sometime turn it on right after, but sometimes i have to push the button twice. Generally it fires up right away each turn off.

Comment: Ok... I think the answer below may be accurate... some sort of other internal damage (or still dead power connector)... I was just trying to rule out heat issues just in case the heatsink had come loose.

Comment: Maybe it damaged the power cord connector also? Try another AC adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that the traces (wires) in the motherboard's printed circuit board (PCB) have been damaged or broken near the power connector, due to the fall.  If this is the case your motherboard might very well be shot.  You can send it to the manufacturer to have them test it; usually for a fee.